# Quickly draw pixels in WinForm in a container

Tags: c#, pixel, system.drawing

I have a sizable form and the location in which a pixel is drawn moves, I have a panel which is the desired image size 400,200 - how can I change individual pixels on this panel? I also need the fastest change possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDI+ does not have a method to set a single pixel, however you can set a 1x1 rectangle to achieve the same effect in your `OnPaint` event. It feels somewhat like a hack, however there is no standard way of doing this.

```
SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    SetPixel(brush, e.Graphics, 10, 10, Color.Red);
}

public void SetPixel(SolidBrush brush, Graphics graphics, int x, int y, Color color)
{
    brush.Color = color;
    graphics.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, 1, 1);
}
```

You could also access the bitmap directly and use it's `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` methods, however they are generally very slow if your pixels need to be updated quickly.

Comment: Thanks, What is `graphics`?

Comment: `graphics` is your GDI Graphics object that you can use when you override a controls `OnPaint` method. Right click your panel, and click **Properties**, then click the events tab and add an event for `Paint`

Comment: I've updated my answer with an implementation that also supports colors

Comment: Thank you, needed that for the EE blocks c;

Comment: Wait, are you Banana_Venom from EE? Or do you mean something else by EE?

Comment: No, someone else lurking in the shadows.

Comment: I don't think we've ever spoken, just noticed you from the forum

Comment: I know you as EEBeast